# Find all possible functions, $F(r)$, harmonic in $2$ and $3$ dimensions,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-functions

Sources: this is an old advanced calculus exam question, which I think is asking for harmonic functions.

The problem statement is:

> Suppose $F(r)$ is a smooth function of $r$ for $r>0$ . Define $\Phi(x) = F(|x|)$ with $x = (x_1, ...,x_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $|x| = (\large \sum_i^dx_i^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.For $d=2$ and $d=3$, find all possible functions $F(r)$ so that
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^d (\frac {\partial}{\partial x_i})^2\Phi(x) = 0.$$

Any hints or comments are welcome.

So, it appears that this problem statement is just a tricky way  of asking to find all functions $\Phi$ such that

$$\Phi_{x_1x_1} + \Phi_{x_2x_2} = 0 $$

and

$$\Phi_{x_1x_1} + \Phi_{x_2x_2} + \Phi_{x_3x_3} = 0$$

I.e., we are looking for all functions that are harmonic.  But what is weird about this question is that it doesn't really specify a *domain* in which we are to find these harmonic functions.  Unless the domain is simply understood to be for all $| x| \ne 0$.

Thanks,

Comment: The definition $\Phi(x) = F(|\vec x|)$ tells you that $\Phi(x)$ needs to be radially symmetric. This is more restrictive than just being harmonic.

Comment: Hi @JimmyK4542, I spent some time reading some online sources on radial functions but am still a bit confused about what makes a function "radial".  Is it the inputs, say, |x|, which could be viewed as rays from the origin onto the perimeter of a circle or sphere that make the function radial, or do the *outputs* have a radial shape - like the equation for the circle or sphere, but these aren't *functions*, though.  What do you think?  For instance, one source said that a function is radial if it is of the form $F(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ ..but it says nothing about its outputs and its shape.Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy enough to carry out the calculation for all $d$.
$$
   \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_j^2}F(r)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(F'(r)\frac{x_j}{r}\right)=F''(r)\frac{x_j^2}{r^2}+F'(r)\frac{1}{r}-F'(r)\frac{x_j^2}{r^3}
$$
Adding these together gives
\begin{align}
              \nabla^2 F(r) &= F''(r)+F'(r)\frac{d}{r}-F'(r)\frac{1}{r} \\
                            &= F''(r)+F'(r)\frac{d-1}{r}.
\end{align}
In order to have a harmonic function $F(r)$ for $d \ge 2$, it is necessary and sufficient that, for $d > 1$,
$$
                 rF''(r)+(d-1)F'(r)=0 \\
                    (r^{d-1}F'(r))'=0,\\
                     F'(r)=\frac{C}{r^{d-1}}.
$$
For $d=2$, the solutions are
$$
                        F(r)=A\ln r + B
$$
For $d\ge 3$, the solutions are
$$
                        F(r)= A\frac{1}{r^{d-2}}+B.
$$

Comment: Hi @TrialandError, how do you perform the calculations on the first of equations that you gave?  Is it just an application of the chain rule?

Comment: @User001 : Yes, the chain rule, and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}r = \frac{x_j}{r}$.

Comment: Hi @TrialAndError, I think your first term in the second derivative should be $F''(r) \frac {x_j}{r}$ ...

Comment: Nevermind @TrialAndError, I found my mistake...just tricky and tedious chain rule stuff to watch out for.

Comment: Very neat calculation, BTW - thanks so much for sharing.  Have a great night @ TrialandError,

Comment: Hi @TrialAndError, I have one silly follow-up question, if you don't mind:  of course, it was necessary to use the chain rule to find necessary and sufficient conditions to solve the Laplace equation.  But after doing so, you then treated $F$ as a function of only one variable $r$, when you put together $(r^{d-1}F'(r))'$.  Is there no need to use chain rule / reverse chain rule here?  So that we don't need to think of $r$ as a function of $x$ and $y$.  If that makes any sense at all...thanks,

Comment: @User001 : The condition that $\nabla^2 F(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_d^2})=0$ in $0 < |x| < \infty$ was found to be equivalent to $F''(r)+F'(r)\frac{d-1}{r}=0$ for the real variable $r > 0$. This holds for all $r$ because $r=|x|$ takes on every positive real value. The real equation was then solved.

Comment: Ah, ok got it.  Thanks so much @TrialAndError -- have a great day :-)

Answer (score 2):

Added later: Let me finish the argument here, because it's quite simple. Suppose $u$ is harmonic and radial on $U = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$ Consider the radial harmonic function

$$v(z) = u(1) + \frac{u(2)-u(1)}{\ln 2}\ln|z|, z \in U.$$

Then $u=v$ on the boundary of the the annulus $A=\{1<|z|<2\}.$ By the maximum/minimum principle for harmonic functions, $u=v$ in all of $A.$ The harmonic function $u-v$ is then harmonic on $U$ and vanishes on an open subset of $U.$ Again by the maximum principle, $u-v\equiv 0$ in $U.$

Thus $u$ has the form $a + b\ln |z|,$ for constants $a,b.$ Conversely, $a + b\ln |z|$ is radial and harmonic on $U$ for any constants $a,b.$

In $\mathbb R^n,n>2,$ we can replace $\ln |z|$ by the radial harmonic function $|x|^{2-n};$ the argument then will be exactly the same.

---

Previous hint: In each case you have seen examples of radial harmonic functions. There are the constants for example. But there are others (not many though). Use these functions to match the values of $\Phi$ on the boundary of any annular region centered at the origin.

Comment: Nice to hear from you @zhw. :-)  And thanks for your answer.  I like the computation done explicitly by TrialAndError (see below), so I will be accepting his (or her) answer.  From reading some online sources, I knew the logarithm had to be involved - in fact, on a set of MIT OCW online notes / recap, it was specifically stated that the only functions were of the form Clog(r), but I didn't know how justify it. Turns out it is just simple but tedious chain rule applications used in solving the Laplace equation :-)  Have a great night...

Comment: I added to my earlier hint.